# Get time periods between timestamp records when some duplicates exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

Here is my example data:

```
declare @Test table (SiteIdentifier int, SysTm datetime2(0), Signalet varchar(21));

insert into @Test (SiteIdentifier, SysTm, Signalet)
values
(587451, '2021-02-28 20:12:03', 'Joined'),
(587451, '2021-03-01 00:00:00', 'Left'),
(587451, '2021-03-04 07:12:17', 'Joined'),
(587451, '2021-03-05 02:13:03', 'Left'),
(587451, '2021-03-05 02:13:03', 'Left'),
(587451, '2021-03-05 07:13:00', 'Joined'),
(587451, '2021-03-08 01:04:07', 'Joined');
```

And here is a query which nearly solves my problem:

```
with cte as (
    select *
      , row_number() over (partition by SiteIdentifier, Signalet order by SysTm) rn
    from @Test
)
select C1.SiteIdentifier, C1.SysTm, coalesce(C2.SysTm, C3.SysTm), datediff(hour, C1.SysTm, coalesce(C2.SysTm, C3.SysTm))
from cte C1
left join cte C2 on C2.SiteIdentifier = C1.SiteIdentifier and C2.Signalet = 'Joined' and C2.rn = C1.rn and C2.SysTm > C1.SysTm
left join cte C3 on C3.SiteIdentifier = C1.SiteIdentifier and C3.Signalet = 'Joined' and C3.rn = C1.rn + 1 and C3.SysTm > C1.SysTm and C2.rn is null
where C1.Signalet = 'Left'
order by C1.SysTm asc;
```

This works as long as `Signalet` alternates between `Left`, `Joined`, `Left`, `Joined`, etc per `SiteIdentifier`.

However, in the live data, there sometimes occurs times where `Joined` (or `Left`) can occur twice within milliseconds of each other - as shown in the sample data. So when `Joined` or `Left` occurs multiple times in a row, all but the first record should be ignored. As should the first record if it is `Joined` because the sequence must always start with `Left`.

I then need to calculate the time difference between the `Left` and the following `Joined` record.

```
    (587451, '2021-02-28 20:12:03', 'Joined'),<-- Skipped
    (587451, '2021-03-01 00:00:00', 'Left'),<-- Used
    (587451, '2021-03-04 07:12:17', 'Joined'),<-- Used
    (587451, '2021-03-05 02:13:03', 'Left'),<-- Skipped
    (587451, '2021-03-05 02:13:03', 'Left'),<-- Used
    (587451, '2021-03-05 07:13:00', 'Joined'),<-- Skipped
    (587451, '2021-03-08 01:04:07', 'Joined');<-- Used
```

The result from the sample data above, should look like:

```
    ID     Left                  Joined                Hours
    587451 '2021-03-01 00:00:00' '2021-03-04 07:12:17' 79
    587451 '2021-03-05 02:13:03' '2021-03-05 07:13:00' 5
```

Disregarding the first `Joined` (which the query above does) because it's not preceded by a `Left`. However, my query fails to produce this result, because of the times there are two equal `Signalet` after another, instead of alternating.

UPDATED DATA / QUESTION:
Here is `actual` data from the live table, that returns NULL:

```
    ID
    15220 '2021-03-13 23:19:57.243' Left
    15220 '2021-03-15 05:54:01.027' Joined
    15220 '2021-03-15 23:29:44.043' Left
    15220 '2021-03-16 05:30:27.790' Joined
```

This returns, using the updated query from above:

```
    15220 '2021-03-13 23:19:57.243' NULL NULL
    15220 '2021-03-15 23:29:44.043' NULL NULL
```

It registers correct rows, but it can't "find" the `joined` and `Hours`

Explanation:
I am trying to get the `difference` in `hours`, between a `Left` signal and a `Joined` signal (all signals are in the same table, hence CTE). It needs to take into account that a first signal can be `Joined`, and that there can be two `Left` or two `Joined` signals directly after another. If the first signal is `Joined`, then disregard that and move to the first occurrence of `Left`, and when there are two `Joined` or two `Left` directly after another, only use the first of the two, disregarding the last one.

Comment: I don't understand the question here, you don't appear to really ask one. A question should be complete on it's own, and it seems that your previous question is required reading here for us to attempt to answer this. [Edit] this question to give us all the details in this question.

Comment: It would really help if you would explain what you are trying to accomplish.  It seems buried in there somewhere, but it is really hard to figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: I edited the question and added an explanation section, trying to step-by-step explain what it is I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following gives the desired result. Its done by eliminating rows which repeat in the first CTE. And then using your existing CTE as the second. So it `lag`s Signalet for the each SiteIdentifier, and then removes any which repeat.

I even managed to filter out the first row if it is "Joined" thereby eliminating the need for the original second join.

```
with cte1 as (
    select *
        , lag(Signalet) over (partition by SiteIdentifier order by SysTm asc) SignaletLagged
        , row_number() over (partition by SiteIdentifier order by SysTm) rn1
    from @Test
),
cte2 as (
    select *
        , row_number() over (partition by SiteIdentifier, Signalet order by SysTm) rn2
    from cte1
    -- Ignore repeated rows i.e. only take the first
    where (SignaletLagged is null or Signalet != SignaletLagged)
    -- Ignore groups which start with Joined, we need a left to start.
    and not (rn1 = 1 and Signalet = 'Joined')
)
select C1.SiteIdentifier, C1.SysTm [Left], C2.SysTm [Joined], datediff(hour, C1.SysTm, C2.SysTm) [Hours]
from cte2 C1
left join cte2 C2 on C2.SiteIdentifier = C1.SiteIdentifier and C2.Signalet = 'Joined' and C2.rn2 = C1.rn2 and C2.SysTm > C1.SysTm
where C1.Signalet = 'Left'
order by C1.SysTm asc;
```

Returns:

| SiteIdentifier | Left | Joined | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 587451 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | 2021-03-04 07:12:17 | 79 |
| 587451 | 2021-03-05 02:13:03 | 2021-03-05 07:13:00 | 5 |

Comment: Testing now :) I'll get back to you shortly

Comment: @Geir note I just improved it by removing the second join.

Comment: @[Dale K] I tested the query, but it returns NULL, and I don't understand why. I have used your latest edit, and I have edited the question with fresh ACTUAL data from the 
live database.

Comment: @Geir at this stage I would suggest that you take the time to learn/understand how the query works and then debug it. If I was in your shoes, and had strangers write me quite a complex query, which I couldn't maintain, I would be uncomfortable with that. There are 3 parts to the query above, you start with the first one and see its returning the correct data, you add the second and again see what data is being returned, then add on the third. At some point you'll see data being excluded/included that shouldn't be and be able to solve the problem.

Comment: I never implement something in the database without understanding (at least the basics) of what a query does. I've never used LAG function, so I'm reading up on that one. I'll just have to continue to debug everything and try my best...

Comment: @Geir I did fix it - it was the partition by in the first row_number... see if you can work out why.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to look at it at all today, as the day has been crazy busy with other work. I'd love to know what you did, so I can compare and understand the differences. My CTE, PARTITION and similar - knowledge is only in the learning stages :/

Comment: I explained how to go about that in my earlier comment, start from the first query work out how that removes duplicates, then move to the next query, then move to the last query.

Comment: I worked on this for hours yesterday, going line by line; seeing what results I got how to work with the results and how the results was affected. I still couldn't understand what the problem in the partition in the first row_number is...

Comment: @Geir because the first row number is purely for detecting whether the first row for a `SiteIdentifier` is `Joined` and if it is then excluding it. So it was originally partitioned by `Signalet` as well, but that was an error because it would give row number 1 for both `Left` and `Joined` which was not correct.

Comment: Ah! Thanks! I am now going to work some more on the Fiddle I've been testing with, and when everything is looking good, maybe try and implement it on the live db.

Comment: I just did, just have been so busy, I haven't had a chance to do it until now.. I'm asking a new questions though, because it turns out the Live data isn't Left / Joined, but another string, that makes the query return weird results... Left / Joined works as intended, but when Left (which is actually a 'ANCL......') and Joined is actually a 'ANOP......' - It doesn't work, even though I changed what I though was necessary.